# Strange vim regular expressions behaviour

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I am not sure what exactly is going on here but I was trying to remove some data from a file using vim. The data is 6 comma separated vales. I want to remove the last three from every line. I used the regular expression find replace `%s/,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*$//g`. I use it on the following data:

```
7.95630550,-3.53701925,-1.04588318,52,40,40
2.60749245,-3.85793233,0.43392944,77,41,19
10.12495995,1.63384104,1.23306274,40,31,42
10.14402199,-3.11163330,1.23091125,40,29,36
-0.49531555,-3.59129953,-1.24293518,62,53,52
```

And i get this:

```
7.95630550,-3.53701925,-1.04588318
2.60749245,-3.85793233,0.43392944
10.12495995,1.63384104,1.23306274,40,31,42
10.14402199,-3.11163330,1.23091125,40,29,36
-0.49531555,-3.59129953,-1.24293518
```

So some of the data is removed but for some reason the data in those other lines is not removed. This is happening all over the file and I cant see any describable pattern? Is there something wrong with my expression?

Comment: Probably trailing spaces on those two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `regex` should work if the number of fields is constant as it is searching from the beginning of the line.

```
:g/\(.\{-}\zs,\)\{3}/normal nd$
```

On each line go the 3 occurrence of `,` and delete to the end of line.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, your command works as intended on the given sample, here, so the problem is probably outside of your regular expression.

But why make it so damn complicated?

```
:%norm $3F,D
```

Comment: This command is cool! but doesn't do the work. it lease the last char behind. Instead code like `%normal $3F,D` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with delimited files, you can use the compliment of the delimiter, by specifying it in a character class -- e.g. if the delimiter is `,`, the compliment is `[^,]`

```
%s/\(,[^,]\+\)\{3\}$//
```

This replaces 3 of the group of "comma, followed by one or more non-comma characters" followed by end of line. with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use cut:

```
:%!cut -d, -f 1-3
```

- Cut extracts text from a file for more help see `man cut`
- `-d,` set comma as the delimiter
- `-f 1-3` you want to "cut" or extract fields 1-3
- `:%!{cmd}` filter the entire file through shell command, `{cmd}`. See `:h :range!`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an asterisk on the last one and you don't need /g at the end:

```
:%s/,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*$//
```

That being said, to make it safer, you probably want to use the + instead of the *, and in that case you need to escape it:

```
:%s/,[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+$//
```

Comment: Hey sorry, this is just a typo in writing the question. The no * would have meant that none of the lines worked though.

Comment: Also the changes you suggested are not working. Could it be the formatting of the lines?

Comment: Maybe if you have some spaces or a hidden ^M, although vim is good at showing those usually... The spaces could be captured with something like `[0-9]*[ ]*$`, you may also use \s instead of just a space.

Comment: Also, I'm not too sure why you shown `%` instead of `:`, but you may want to use `:0,$` or select the lines you want to change and then press `:` then it will show you `:'<,'>` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Again another typo, `:%s` does all the lines in the file.

Comment: Okay 8-) Did you check for spaces or other control characters on the lines that do not get affected?

Comment: No spaces or control characters that I can see?